# Приложение-тестер на Android с SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, orientation

Пытаюсь создать приложение, задачей которого является проверка ответов на тестовые вопросы. Пользователь выбирает номер задачи в окне выбора задач, переходит в окно, где ему демонстрируется условие задачи. В поле ввода вводит ответ. В случае ввода правильного ответа в этом окне выводится сообщение "Правильный ответ", в случае неправильного - "Неправильныый". После возврата в окно выбора заданий результат засчитывается в виде очка (1 или 0) и показывается напротив каждого задания. Очки по всем заданиям суммируются и показываются в отдельном поле.При создании приложения опирался на книгу "Программирование для профессионалов" Харди, Филлипса, в том числе в части использования "CursorWrapper".
   До тех пор, пока для хранения условий задач использовал ресурсы строк особых проблем не было - приложение выполняло основную функцию. Только после смены ориентации экрана, после возврата в окно выбора задач, результаты решения задачи исчезают... 
   Но когда для хранения условий задач стал использовать SQLite приложение стало вообще вылетать при переходе из окна выбора задач в окно условия конкретной задачи.

Вот структура приложения:
MainActivity.  Активность, управляющая двумя фрагментами. В фрагменте calculon_fragment (Окно выбора заданий) осуществляется выбор задания и показываются очки за решения каждого задания в отдельности. В фрагменте rezult_fragment показывается сумма очков по всем заданиям.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
calculon_fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    private static final String KEY_COUNT = "COUNT";
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
    int m;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            m = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_COUNT, 0);
        }
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    }
    public void OnFragmentInteraction(int k){
        rezult_fragment fragment = (rezult_fragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_rezult);
        if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()){
            fragment.setText(Integer.toString(k));
            m=k;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        OnFragmentInteraction(m);
        outState.putInt(KEY_COUNT,m);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    }
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        OnFragmentInteraction(m);
        m = savedInstanceState.getInt("count");
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");
    }
}
```

Первый фрагмент

```
public class calculon_fragment extends Fragment {
    private Calculon mCalculon;
    Button task1;
    Button task2;
    Button task3;
    TextView Text1;
    TextView Text2;
    TextView Text3;
    private static final int REQUEST_REZULT = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_REZULT1 = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_REZULT2 = 2;
    private int mBulle1;
    private int mBulle2;
    private int mBulle3;
    int countIn;
    int rezultbull;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mCalculon = new Calculon(); 
    } 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calculon_fragment, container, false);
        Text1 = (TextView)v. findViewById(R.id.view_1);
        Text2 = (TextView)v. findViewById(R.id.view_2);
        Text3 = (TextView)v. findViewById(R.id.view_3);

        task1 = (Button)v. findViewById(R.id.button);
        task2 = (Button)v. findViewById(R.id.button2);
        task3 = (Button)v. findViewById(R.id.button3);

        task1.setOnClickListener(Naming1);
        task2.setOnClickListener(Naming2);
        task3.setOnClickListener(Naming3);
        return v;

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_REZULT) {
            if (data == null) {
                return;
            }
            mBulle1 = Main2Activity.wasAnswerShown(data);
            Text1.setText(Integer.toString(mBulle1));
        }
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_REZULT1) {
            if (data == null) {
                return;
            }
            mBulle2 = Main2Activity.wasAnswerShown(data);
            Text2.setText(Integer.toString(mBulle2));
        }
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_REZULT2) {
            if (data == null) {
                return;
            }
            mBulle3 = Main2Activity.wasAnswerShown(data);
            Text3.setText(Integer.toString(mBulle3));
        }
        rezultbull = mBulle1+mBulle2+mBulle3;
        mListener.OnFragmentInteraction(rezultbull);
    }

    interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void OnFragmentInteraction (int k);
    }

    public void onAttach (Context context) {
super.onAttach(context);
mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;

    }


    View.OnClickListener Naming1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int countIn = 0;
            Intent intent = Main2Activity.newIntent(getActivity(), countIn);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_REZULT);

        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener Naming2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int countIn = 1;
            Intent intent = Main2Activity.newIntent(getActivity(), countIn);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_REZULT1);
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener Naming3 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int countIn = 2;
            Intent intent = Main2Activity.newIntent(getActivity(), countIn);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_REZULT2);
        }
    };
}
```

Второй фрагмент

```
public class rezult_fragment extends Fragment {
    Button open;
    TextView RezultShower;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rezult_fragment, container, false);
        open = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.view_rezult);

        RezultShower = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.view_integral);
        return view;

    }

    public void setText (String item) {
    RezultShower.setText(item);
}
}
```

Окно условий Main2Activity. Выводит условие. Вводится попытка ответа. Результат ответа. Кнопка переход к следующему заданию. Возврат в окно выбора заданий

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText InputAnswer;
    TextView Rezult;
    Button mNMM;
    Button Next;
    Button ButtonBack;
    int n=1;
    private static final String EXTRA_COUNTER =
            "com.bignerdranch.android.TestFromBase.counter";
    private static final String EXTRA_TESTER =
            "com.bignerdranch.android.TestFromBase.tester";
    private static final String EXTRA_TESTER2 =
            "com.bignerdranch.android.TestFromBase.tester2";
    private int mCounter2;

    private Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    TextView mTaskCondition;
    public Double Real;
    String mTaskConditionTo;

    public Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, int countIn){
        Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext,Main2Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_COUNTER,countIn);
        return intent;
    }

    private int mCurrentIndex = mCounter2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        mCounter2 = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_COUNTER, 0);
        mCurrentIndex = mCounter2;

        InputAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.view_3);

        mTaskCondition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view_1);
        mTaskConditionTo = mTaskCondition.toString();

            Rezult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view_2);

        Next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Next.setOnClickListener(Cliker);

        mNMM=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        mNMM.setOnClickListener(Cliker2);

        ButtonBack=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonback);
        ButtonBack.setOnClickListener(Cliker3);

    };

public static class ObjectA {
    String Task;
    Double Answer;
    UUID mUUID;

    public ObjectA() {
    }

    public UUID getUUID() {
        return mUUID;
    }

    public String getTask() {
        return Task;
    }

    public Double getAnswer() {
        return Answer;
    }

    public void setTask(String task) {
        Task = task;
    }

    public void setAnswer(Double answer) {
        Answer = answer;
    }
}

    newBASE nB;
    SQLiteDatabase db = nB.getReadableDatabase();

    public TaskCursorWrapper queryTask(String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = (TaskCursorWrapper) db.query(
                TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{newBASE.nwTABLE.TASK},
                whereClause,
                whereArgs,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        return new TaskCursorWrapper(cursor);
    }

    public String getObjectB() {
        TaskCursorWrapper mTaskCursorWrapper = queryTask(null, null);
        ObjectA O = new ObjectA();
                mTaskCursorWrapper.moveToNext();
                mTaskConditionTo = O.getTask();

        return mTaskConditionTo;
    }

    public Double getObjectC() {
        TaskCursorWrapper mTaskCursorWrapper = queryTask(null, null);
        ObjectA O = new ObjectA();
        Real = O.getAnswer();
        return Real;
    }

    View.OnClickListener Cliker = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getObjectB();
        }
    };

        private void checkAnswer (double Trying, int n)
    {
        double ValidAnswer = getObjectC();
        Trying= Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(InputAnswer.getText()));
        if (Trying==ValidAnswer){
            Rezult.setText(R.string.RezultOk);
            setBull(1);
        }
        else {
            Rezult.setText(R.string.RezultNon);
                setBull(0);
        }
    }

    private void setBull(int n){
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra(EXTRA_TESTER,n);
setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
    }


public static int wasAnswerShown(Intent result) {
        return result.getIntExtra(EXTRA_TESTER,1);
}


    View.OnClickListener Cliker2 = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            checkAnswer(0.00, 0);
        }
    };
    View.OnClickListener Cliker3 = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed(
            );
        }
    };
}
```

Классы баз данных (размещены в пакете database).

```
public class newBASE extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
        public static final String COMA_SEP = ",";
        public final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
                "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + " (" + nwTABLE._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                        + nwTABLE.TASK + " text" + COMA_SEP
                        + nwTABLE.ANSWER + " real" + COMA_SEP +
                        ");";
        public static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
                "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME;
        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "newBASE.db";
        public newBASE(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
    public class nwTABLE implements BaseColumns {
            public static final String TABLE_NAME = "mathprofi";
            public static final String TASK = "task";
            public static final String ANSWER = "answer";}
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(nwTABLE.TASK, R.string.task1);
            values.put(nwTABLE.ANSWER, "0.31");
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            values.put(nwTABLE.TASK, R.string.task2);
            values.put(nwTABLE.ANSWER, "0.38");
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            values.put(nwTABLE.TASK, R.string.task3);
            values.put(nwTABLE.ANSWER, "0.5");
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            values.put(nwTABLE.TASK, R.string.task4);
            values.put(nwTABLE.ANSWER, "0.58");
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            values.put(nwTABLE.TASK, R.string.task5);
            values.put(nwTABLE.ANSWER, "0.95");
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            values.put(nwTABLE.TASK, R.string.task6);
            values.put(nwTABLE.ANSWER, "0.8836");
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        }
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int nerVersion) {
            db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
            onCreate(db);
        }
        public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
        }
    }
```

Для управления доступом

```
public final class TaskCursorWrapper extends CursorWrapper {
    public TaskCursorWrapper(Cursor cursor) {
        super(cursor);
    }

    public Main2Activity.ObjectA getObjectA() {
        String task = getString(getColumnIndex(newBASE.nwTABLE.TASK));
        Double answer = getDouble(getColumnIndex(newBASE.nwTABLE.ANSWER));

        Main2Activity.ObjectA O = new Main2Activity.ObjectA();
        O.setTask(task);
        O.setAnswer(answer);

        return O;
    }
}
```

Чтобы не загромождать сообщение не привожу xml-разметку. Если потребуется приведу. 
  Буду признателен за помощь в поиске ошибки.

Comment: не совсем понял, а где я таковые создаю...